# modifying a php DateTime object

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

I have a question regarding the proper way to modify a php DateTime object.  Currently, I'm doing something like:

```
$origEvent = new DateTime(...);
$newEvent = new DateTime(...);
$someOtherEvent = new DateTime(...);

//get the time difference between the orignal event and the edited event
$diff = $origEvent->diff($newEvent);

$someOtherEvent->add($diff);
```

Using the DateTime::add() method *seems* to work whether we are adding or subtracting time from $someOtherEvent.  Is this the correct way to do this?  I know there is DateTime::sub() used for subtracting time, but it seems that as long as the DateInterval (produced by the $origEvent->diff()) has the inverted flag, the DateTime::add() knows to actually subtract time.  Is this correct?  Should I be using something like DateTime::modify?

Comment: @hakre Not that it matters at all, I was just curious why the tags were changed?  The functions I was referring to are only available in php5, so I figured specificity was important.  Again, doesn't matter to me, just curious for future posts :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, DateTime::diff() returns the difference between two DateTime objects in a relative manner. Thus :

- If date1 is lower than date2 then date1->diff(date2) will result in a *negative* interval
- If date2 is lower than date1 then date1->diff(date2) will result in a *positive* interval

So :

- The use of DateTime::add() with a negative interval is equivalent to the use of DateTime::sub() with the **absolute** value of this same interval
- The use of DateTime::sub() with a negative interval is equivalent to the use of DateTime::add() with the **absolute** value of this same interval

For reasons of clarity of the code you can set the second parameter of DateTime::diff() to true in order to get an absolute difference every time and then choose the best function between DateTime::add() and DateTime::sub() knowing that you have an absolute difference.

Some words about the choice between DateTime::modify() and DateTime::add(), DateTime:sub() :

- As long as you are using DateTime::diff() you are assuming that your PHP version is greater than or equal to 5.3.0, and you can use all new functions available in this PHP version; that is to say DateTime::add() and DateTime::sub()
- The use of DateTime::modify() is justified when your PHP version is greater than or equal to 5.2.0. (In this version DateTime::add() and DateTime::sub() are not yet available)

Comment: Ah, hadn't seen that second argument of the diff method.  I think your right, I felt icky using just the add function (even though it works as I thought it would) thus this post was born.  Thanks for the clarity, much appreciated.

Comment: As Ruby programming language states: "Code should be crystal clear, good code tells the reader exactly what it is trying to do. Great code shouts its intent." So by using just the add function, the understanding of your code becomes more complex. And by using the right function in the right circumstance your code becomes more clear. You're Welcome ;)